# triggering a tag click sometimes causes page to reload

Tags: javascript

When on a Facebook profile you have the about tab/page with a navigation bar to the left. Im trying to trigger a click on the appropriate navigation bar; however sometimes the page will reload with that url and the content, yet other times it doesn't need to reload and just renders the content. This seem to random.

I have noticed when the page doesn't force a reload of the page then it works fine however many times i use the click event on each of the different navigation links

`x = document.querySelector('li[label="Contact and basic info"] > a');`
`x.click();`

Comment: why don't you just do `location.href = x.href`

Comment: i want to try and avoid page reloads as i loop through the menus